# How does continuity of $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ imply that $h: X \rightarrow Y\times Y$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

How does continuity of $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ imply that $h: X \rightarrow Y\times Y$ is continuous?

Comment: Presumably $h$ is defined as $h(x)=(f(x),g(x))$? Otherwise how are $f$ and $g$ relevant to anything?

Comment: I suppose $X$, $Y$ are arbitrarily topological space...? If yes, you should mention that in your question and [tag:general-topology] tag might be appopriate.

Comment: This might be useful (although you can also try to find a more direct proof): [Continuous Mapping to Topological Product](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Mapping_to_Topological_Product) at ProofWiki.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $h$ is defined as $h(x)=(f(x),g(x))$, then $h$ is continuous because (by definition) the collection
$$\{U\times V\mid U,V\text{ open subsets of }Y\}$$
is a basis for the product topology on $Y\times Y$, and
$$h^{-1}(U\times V)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\in U\text{ and }g(x)\in V\}=f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$$
is open for any open $U,V\subseteq Y$ because $f$ and $g$ are continuous.